# Errors when getting JSON result into ListView

Tags: php, android, json, android-listview, android-json

***UPDATE 4: Problem Solved Check my Answer Below***

I am trying to retreive JSON result from PHP Webservice and save it into ListView But I got an errors

I'm not sure what is my mistake could you help me please

I was following this tutorial from Travis (mybringback)

http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/13239/android-mysql-php-json-part-6-json-parsing-and-android-design/

His method (Only on this part) doesn't require any Parameters to get Posts (and it is actually workis using HIS PHP Method) 
But My web Service Method require 2 Parameters (kioskid (device ID), accesstoken) which are saved in SharedPreferense

<del>Update1:</del>

I modified the Android code also uninstall the old one and start from beginig (Login and so on) until i get to EventListActivity But no List is showing and I got only one error Line in Log (no error message  in the device)

<del>Update2: After Modifying the code and separating ***UpdateJSON()*** and trying to get JSON Response in  ***doInBackground()***</del>

<del>update 3: I Added JSONParse Class</del>

I got a new Error message  that I'm getting NullPointerexception at ***setListAdapter(adapter)*** inside the method ***updateList()***

**this is the error Log:**

```
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196): Process: com.test.event, PID: 16196
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getCount(SimpleAdapter.java:93)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:480)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at android.app.ListActivity.setListAdapter(ListActivity.java:265)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at com.decoder.tapway.event1.EventListActivity.updateList(EventListActivity.java:140)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at com.decoder.tapway.event1.EventListActivity.access$3(EventListActivity.java:136)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at com.decoder.tapway.event1.EventListActivity$LoadEvents.onPostExecute(EventListActivity.java:221)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at com.decoder.tapway.event1.EventListActivity$LoadEvents.onPostExecute(EventListActivity.java:1)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-26 16:58:38.397: E/AndroidRuntime(16196):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**this is the PHP function (Yii Framework) that I'm trying to get its JSON result**

```
public function actionEventList(){
        if(isset($_POST['kioskid']) && isset($_POST['accesstoken'])){
            $response = array();

            $kiosk = Kiosk::model()->findByAttributes(array('kioskid'=>$_POST['kioskid'], 'accesstoken'=>$_POST['accesstoken']));
            if($kiosk === null){
                $response['status'] = '0';
                $response['message'] = 'Invalid Kiosk';
            } else {
                $events = Event::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('createdby'=>$kiosk->userid, 'status'=>'A'));
                $list = array();
                foreach($events as $row){
                    $list[] = array('id'=>$row->id, 'name'=>$row->eventname);
                }
                $response['status'] = '1';
                $response['list'] = $list;
            }
            $this->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($response));
        } else {
            $this->_sendResponse(400);
        }
    }
```

**This is my Java code in android: (UPDATED 2)**

The Most Important Method is  ***updateJSONdata()*** that Retrieves recent Events from the server

Then I call that method inside ***doInBackground()***

```
public class EventListActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    // testing on Server:
    private static final String EVENT_LIST_URL = "http://www.XXX.com/XXX/XXX/eventList";



    // JSON IDS:
    private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";
    private static final String TAG_EVENT_LIST = "list";
    private static final String TAG_EVENT_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_EVENT_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    // An array of all of our Events
    private JSONArray jaEvents = null;

    // manages all of our events in a list.
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayEventList;


    // prerepare SharedPreferences file name
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.MyApp.event"; 

    private SharedPreferences sharedPref ;

    String accesstoken, username, kioskid,spKioskid, password ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.event_list_layout);

        // setup SharedPreferences file
        this.sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);

        // get data from previous activity 
        this.accesstoken = sharedPref.getString("accesstoken", null);
        this.kioskid = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        Toast.makeText(EventListActivity.this, "onCreate\n"+kioskid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(EventListActivity.this, "onCreate\n"+accesstoken, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // assign data from SharedPreferences 
        this.accesstoken = sharedPref.getString("accesstoken", null);
        this.kioskid = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        Toast.makeText(EventListActivity.this, "onResume\n"+kioskid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(EventListActivity.this, "onResume\n"+accesstoken, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        // loading the comments via AsyncTask
        new LoadEvents().execute();
    }


    /**
     * Retrieves recent Events from the server.
     */
    public void updateJSONdata() {

        arrayEventList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject jsonObj = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(EVENT_LIST_URL);

        try {

            jaEvents = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_EVENT_LIST);

            // looping through all events according to the json object returned
            for (int i = 0; i < jaEvents.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jaEvents.getJSONObject(i);

                // gets the content of each tag
                String eventID = c.getString(TAG_EVENT_ID);
                String eventName = c.getString(TAG_EVENT_NAME);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_EVENT_ID, eventID);
                map.put(TAG_EVENT_NAME, eventName);

                arrayEventList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
     */
    private void updateList() {
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrayEventList,
                R.layout.single_event_layout, new String[] { TAG_EVENT_ID, TAG_EVENT_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.event_id, R.id.event_name });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();    
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // do something
            }
        });
    }

    public class LoadEvents extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // check for success tag
        int status;
        String accesstoken ;
        String kioskid ;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EventListActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Events...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {


            this.accesstoken = sharedPref.getString("accesstoken", null);
            this.kioskid = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

            try {
                // building parameters for Logout
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accesstoken", accesstoken));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kioskid", kioskid));
                Log.d("request!", "Starting");

                // getting product details by HTTPRequest
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(EVENT_LIST_URL,"POST",params);

                // checking your log for JSON response
                Log.d("Loding Events Attemp", json.toString());

                // assign status to JSON "status" tag
                status = json.getInt(TAG_STATUS);
                if (status == 1){
                    // print in console success message + JSON response message
                    Log.d("Events Loaded Successfully",json.toString());


                    updateJSONdata();

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    // print in console failure message + JSON response message
                    Log.d("Faild loding Events!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            updateList();
        }
    }
}
```

***Update 3***

**JSONParser Class**

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // making HTTP Request
        try {
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            // Extract data from the response.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            // Open an inputStream with the data content.
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
            String line = null;

            // Build the string until null.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Close the input stream.
            is.close();
            // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try to parse the string to a JSON Object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error Parsing data" + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String loginUrl, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
        // making HTTP Request
        try {
            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(loginUrl);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }else 
                // check for request method
                if(method == "GET"){
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                    loginUrl += "?" + paramString;
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(loginUrl);
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
                BufferedReader  reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String  line = null;

                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Buffer Error","Error Converting Reesult "+e.toString());
            }

        // try parse the string to JSON Object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error Parsing data" + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }

}
```

**single_event_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/post_border_style"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/post_background_style"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tapway_event_logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/box"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/event_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:textColor="#888" >
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**event_list_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layover"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/BlackText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/event_list"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_layover"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which line you are getting Null Pointer exception?

Comment: Log.d("Loding Events Attemp", json.toString()); and updateJSONdata(); <inside doInBackground() method>

Comment: That means your json object is null.

Comment: how should I fix this to retrieve data from the PHP code

Comment: Means when you POST your data to server you'r getting json response. But in your case may be your response is null. So properly check that you data properly Posted to server or not. And if your JSON response is right or wrong after post data to server.

Comment: which method you are using , GET or POST?

Comment: @Beginner I am using POST

Comment: @RaJeNdRa Actually I don't have access to to the source code of the PHP just the web services and since it require access token (that given when login) as parameter then I won't be able to test it online <Kind Off>. to test this I have to do code for all previous methods to test this.  (But It's confirm that it works probably )

Comment: check the response code what you are recieving

Comment: @Beginner as I mentioned in my last reply I don't have an access to source code only the web services 
BTW it suppose to work if I pass the parameters in the link like this 
www.XXX.com/eventList&kioskid=fdgsdfdf&accesstoken=fafgsdg

this PHP Script uses Yii framework but I'm getting this error message 
Error 404
The system is unable to find the requested action "eventlist&kioskid=fdgsdfdf&accesstoken=fafgsdg".

Comment: how can I test this in the browser to get JSON response message? (without writing a new php code)

Comment: The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find what was requested.

Comment: @Beginner I understand that, what I mean is how to access to this method in the browser 

I know in Yii framework to access method you have to type Controller name (WsController) followed by its Action name (actionEventList)  so the link should be www.XXX.com/ws/eventList  

but how to test the parameters (I'll get the device ID and access token from my device then I'll typeit in the browser)

Comment: @RaJeNdRa

I modified the code But no List is showing and I got only one error Line

Comment: @Beginner 

I modified the code But no List is showing and I got only one error Line

Comment: @Beginner. check my post again I have updated my question

Comment: How you are passing `kioskid` and `accesstoken` to service?

Comment: accesstoken From SharedPreferences
kioskid from the device itself
when user login to the system he'll reseice an accesstoken for this kioskid This accesstoken saved in sharedpreference file

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Value <!DOCTYPE> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` indicates that you're not getting a JSON response from the server, but a markup document, most probably an error page.

You can either try executing the request outside Android to check whether it's working fine, or you can split your process into two steps:

1. Get a text response from the web service into String, and `Log` it.
2. Parse that String into JSON

That way you will have a log of the response before the parsing fails, so you will have more info.

Comment: The Most Important Method is updateJSONdata() that Retrieves recent Events from the server

Then I call that method inside doInBackground()

check my code and tell how should I do your method

Comment: You will need to replace this line in updateJSONdata(): `JSONObject jsonObj = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(EVENT_LIST_URL);`. Make a normal HTTP request, and then log the String result. It can be more helpful if you provide the JSONParser class you use as well.

Comment: I Provided under EventListActivity

Comment: Great, you already have access to the String there, just log it.
Before 
`// try to parse the string to a JSON Object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error Parsing data" + e.toString());
        }` add `Log.d("JSON", json);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for your responses

I found the mistake

Actually It's just an error passing a wrong parameter

in fact it's a mistake in the web server that there are should be 2 kind of access token 
one for Login and the other for the selected event
But when I select an event the implementation change the one that comes with login to event access token

previously I was working on specific Event ID without to finish other things related to events that's why I didn't notice the changes

**Now Problem Solved**

**Long story  short 
The Code Is Correct**

**thank you again**