# I need help to understand JSON Elements (Response Messages) from this function

Tags: php, android, json, yii, android-json

I am working on a project that previously done with another developer. This project based on PHP Yii framework and mobile side is Android to get JSON messages from the web services that provided in the website.

I'm stuck in this web service function "getStamp"

I don't know what are the JSON response messages. I mean what are the string Values that I'll hold for 'stampID', 'stampName', 'stampImg'.

These are the information that I have:

**request parameters:**

- kioskid
- accesstoken
- tagid
- eventid
- checking = 0 or 1

**for failed response:**

- status = 0
- message = error message

**for success response:**

- status = 1
- tappedStamp = the obtain stamp ID after tapping the device (if checking not equal to 1)
- message = the message of the obtained stamp (if checking not equal to 1)
- collectedStamp = list of collected stamp ID

> If you want to use 'getStamp' web service to do the checking on how
>   many stamps that have been collected by the user, then you pass
>   'checking' as 1. If you want to use that web service to collect the
>   stamp of the kiosk, then you pass 'checking' as 0.

So far as what I understand from the Code and explanation that 'collectedStamp' and 'tappedStamp' are  JSON Object names of a JSON Arrays

I need to know these 3 Elements (I suppose to get it from some where the names are random not real I just make it to explain to you what need)

> 'stampID', 'stampName','stampImg'

```
{ "collectedStamp" : [ { "stampID" : "1",
        "stampName" : "stamp1",
        "stampImg": "stamp1.png"
      },
       { "stampID" : "2",
        "stampName" : "stamp2",
        "stampImg": "stamp2.png"
      },
    ],
  "status" : "1"
}


{ "tappedStamp" : [ { "stampID" : "1",
        "stampName" : "stamp1",
        "stampImg": "stamp1.png"
      },
       { "stampID" : "2",
        "stampName" : "stamp2",
        "stampImg": "stamp2.png"
      },
    ],
  "status" : "1"
}
```

For Android Implementation most likely I'll use the same code that I provided in this post

[Errors when getting JSON result into ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652537/errors-when-getting-json-result-into-listview)

if you see in the web service function in that link you'll find this

```
        $list = array();
        foreach($events as $row){
            $list[] = array('id'=>$row->id, 'name'=>$row->eventname);
        }
        $response['status'] = '1';
        $response['list'] = $list;
    }
```

which means that that the JSON response['list'] Contains 'id' and 'name' objects

and these are the String values that I add it inside ListView Adapter

I need to know the equivalent to 'id' and 'name' in this web Service

**getStamp() Web Service Function:**

```
public function actionGetStamp(){
    if(isset($_POST['kioskid']) && isset($_POST['accesstoken']) && isset($_POST['tagid']) && isset($_POST['eventid']) && isset($_POST['checking'])){
        $response = array();

        $kiosk = Kiosk::model()->findByAttributes(array('kioskid'=>$_POST['kioskid'], 'accesstoken'=>$_POST['accesstoken']));
        if(($kiosk === null || $kiosk->eventid != $_POST['eventid']) && $_POST['accesstoken'] != 'REPOST_SYNC'){
            $response['status'] = '0';
            $response['message'] = 'Invalid Kiosk';
        } else {
            $eventStation = EventStation::model()->findByAttributes(array('eventid'=>$_POST['eventid'],'deviceid'=>$_POST['kioskid']));
            if($eventStation === null){
                $response['status'] = '0';
                $response['message'] = 'Invalid Kiosk';
            } else {
                $tag = EventTag::model()->findByAttributes(array('tagid'=>$_POST['tagid'], 'eventid'=>$eventStation->eventid, 'status'=>'A'));
                if($tag === null || $tag->joinon == null){
                    $response['status'] = '0';
                    $response['message'] = 'Tag is not registered yet.';
                } else {
                    $sql = 'SELECT es.id, (CASE WHEN esc.stampid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) collected,
                            (CASE WHEN es.kioskid = :kioskid THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) tapped,
                            es.message
                            FROM tap_event_stamp es
                            LEFT JOIN tap_event_stamp_collection esc ON es.id = esc.stampid and esc.tagid = :tagid
                            WHERE es.eventid = :eventid AND es.isdeleted = 0
                            GROUP BY es.id ORDER BY es.id
                            ';
                    $params = array(':eventid'=>$_POST['eventid'], ':kioskid'=>$eventStation->id, ':tagid'=>$tag->id);
                    $stamps = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll(true, $params);
                    if(sizeof($stamps) == 0){
                        $response['status'] = '0';
                        $response['message'] = 'Invalid Request';
                    } else {
                        $feature = EventFeatures::model()->findByAttributes(array('eventid'=>$_POST['eventid'],'featureid'=>3));
                        if($feature === null){
                            $response['status'] = '0';
                            $response['message'] = 'Invalid Request';
                        } else {
                            $info = json_decode($feature->info, true);
                            $random = false;
                            if(isset($info['STAMPSEQ'])){
                                $random = $info['STAMPSEQ'] == 'R';
                            }
                            $collected = array();
                            $response['status'] = $_POST['checking'] == 1 ? '1' : '0';
                            $duplicate = false;
                            foreach($stamps as $stamp){
                                if ($stamp['tapped'] == 1 && $_POST['checking'] != 1){
                                    $response['tappedStamp'] = $stamp['id'];
                                    $response['message'] = $stamp['message'];
                                    $response['status'] = '1';
                                    $duplicate = $stamp['collected'] == 1;
                                } elseif($stamp['collected'] == 1){
                                    $collected[] = $stamp['id'];
                                    continue;
                                } elseif(!$random && $_POST['checking'] != 1){
                                    if( !isset($response['tappedStamp']) ){
                                        $response['message'] = 'You have tapped a wrong kiosk';
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if( $response['status'] == '1' ){
                                $response['collectedStamp'] = $collected;
                                if(!$duplicate && $_POST['checking'] != 1){
                                    $newRecord = new StampCollection();
                                    $newRecord->eventid = $_POST['eventid'];
                                    $newRecord->tagid = $tag->id;
                                    $newRecord->kioskid = $eventStation->id;
                                    $newRecord->stampid = $response['tappedStamp'];
                                    $newRecord->collectedon = time();
                                    $newRecord->save();
                                }
                            }
                            if( $response['status'] == '1' && Yii::app()->params['isOffline'] && $_POST['checking'] != 1){
                                $params = array();
                                $params['tagid'] = $_POST['tagid'];
                                $params['eventid'] = $_POST['eventid'];
                                $params['kioskid'] = $_POST['kioskid'];
                                $params['accesstoken'] = 'REPOST_SYNC';

                                $model = new PendingRequest();
                                $model->request_url = '/ws/getStamp';
                                $model->request_param = json_encode($params);
                                $model->createdon = time();
                                $model->issent = 0;
                                $model->save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $this->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($response));
    } else {
        $this->_sendResponse(400);
    }
}
```

One more question:

How can I check the web service from the Browser and pass the parameter (this Project uses Yii Framework)? So I can get JSON message either from browser.

**Update:**

After using "POSTMAN REST Client" I got this message

if checking = 1

```
{"status":"1","collectedStamp":[]}
```

if checking = 0

this is the HTML Code I got

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0rJZJK8qFz9MENzcWxhU3NPalk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have tried http://json.parser.online.fr/beta/ to under json

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?utm_source=plus

Comment: Try `echo json_encode($resoponse);` in your php

Comment: I tried to to that but it keep giving me this message:

400 Bad Request

Apache Server at www.xxxxxxxxx.com Port 80

Comment: Event after I remove 
} else {
        $this->_sendResponse(400);
    }

Comment: You have to check your url is working or not?

Comment: I used POSTMAN REST Client I'll update my Post now with the result

Comment: Please refer this link it may help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935481/parsing-jsonarray-in-android/22935769#comment35014069_22935769